# How can I reorient a pane and make it full screen height in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In tmux I currently have these window positions:

```
+---------------------+
|                     |
|         1           |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|         2           |
|                     |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|         3           |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

I then want to take the third pane and move it vertical and full height, like this:

```
+-------------+-------+
|             |       |
|     1       |       |
|             |       |
|             |       |
+-------------+   3   |
|             |       |
|     2       |       |
|             |       |
|             |       |
+-------------+-------+
```

Vim has a command for this `<C-w>L` - how can  I do this in tmux?

Comment: AFAICT, you can't do it in `tmux`. You can use `next-layout` command or `bind-key + space` to switch between builtin layout, none of theme can give you your requirement above.

Answer (score 3):

This was the best I could come up with, an realistically may be too messy to use, but if its needed it works.
As per @cuonglm's comments, the basic command to reorganise a windows pane's so - at least one of them  - is full height is:

- <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>

Problem is, what I'm after isn't defined in the preset layouts, so I needed to keep hitting <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> till I got this:

```
+-----+------+------+
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
|  1  |  3   |  2   |
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
+-----+------+------+
```

Then rotate with <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> till I got this:

```
+-----+------+------+
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
|  1  |  2   |  3   |
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
|     |      |      |
+-----+------+------+
```

Then you can go

- <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> - to bring up command prompt
- `:move-pane -h -s 1 -t 0`

Where the `-h` (I guess) means spread the *panes*  horizontally - and doesnt refer to the vertical bar between them.
So finally you get this:

```
+-------------+-------+
|             |       |
|     1       |       |
|             |       |
|             |       |
+-------------+   3   |
|             |       |
|     2       |       |
|             |       |
|             |       |
+-------------+-------+
```